# ReactNative Jest snapshot test is failing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs

I wanted to add TypeScript to my react-native project. I founded [this article](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/05/07/using-typescript-with-react-native.html) and go ahead with it step by step. But when I run `yarn test` I get this error and I don't know why:

```
FAIL  Components/__tests__/Hello.tsx
● Test suite failed to run

Plugin 0 specified in ".../node_modules/babel-preset-react-native/index.js" provided an invalid property of "default"(While processing preset: ".../node_modules/babel-preset-react-native/index.js")

  at Plugin.init (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/plugin.js:131:13)
  at Function.normalisePlugin (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:152:12)
  at node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:184:30
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at Function.normalisePlugins (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:158:20)
  at OptionManager.mergeOptions (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:234:36)
  at node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:265:14
  at node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:323:22
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at OptionManager.resolvePresets (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.865s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "TypeScriptLab",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^23.1.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.6",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.55.28",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "23.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5",
    "jest": "23.3.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.10",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1",
    "ts-jest": "^23.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "\\.(ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "\\.snap$",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "cacheDirectory": ".jest/cache"
  }
}
```

And this is my `Hello.tsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

import { Hello } from '../Hello'

it('renders correctly with defaults', () => {
  const button = renderer
    .create(<Hello name={'World'} enthusiasmLevel={1} />)
    .toJSON()
  expect(button).toMatchSnapshot
})
```

I searched on the Internet but I couldn't find any solution to fix this issue.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I am also stuck here.

Comment: @AshishSinghal I just provided an answer. Please Check it out and I hope it works for you too ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I removed this line from my `package.json` file
`"babel-preset-react-native": "^5"`

And install this package again so it's working now correctly.
`"babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",`